# Use wp_login_form function to login with a custom user table?

Tags: customization, users, wp-login-form

Is it possible to use WP built-in function `wp_login_form` on a custom non-wp user table??

It would be awesome if i could at the non-wp user table as an argument

```
$args = array(
    'redirect' => home_url(), 
    'id_username' => 'user',
    'id_password' => 'pass',
'table_user' =>mycustom_table
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is completly custom coded solution. WordPress doesn't support this (and never will), and I have never heard of the plugin that can do this.

This is not a simple thing to do, and would incolve great deal of changesvto the login process.

Comment: tx Milan, going to try another route. Thinking of creating a custom role and select all users with that specific role and don't allow these users to access the wp-admin part. But let them access the non-wp part of the website (where i do use some WP functions)

What do you think?